# HTTP status code for a resource infected by virus

Tags: http-status-codes, http-proxy, virus

I'm developing an application which acts as an **Http-Proxy** for serving files from an external resource. It actually downloads the file from the external resource, checks for **viruses** and if the file is not infected, returns the file to the client.

My problem is, **in case of the file is infected**, what HTTP Status code my service should return? I suppose that any type of 4xx error codes is not appropriate for that situation because this class of code is intended for Client errors.

Is a 502 (Bad Gateway) error more appropriate?
Is there any kind of Standard that covers this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right maestromarko : 502 Bad Gateway. Read [the specifications here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.3):

> The 502 (Bad Gateway) status code indicates that the server, while
> acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from an
> inbound server it accessed while attempting to fulfill the request.

Your proxy is acting as a Gateway and he received what it conciders is invalid as there are virus in it.

It is not a 4xx class error, because whatever the client changes in the request, the result will still be an error.

See also this [decision diagram](https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html)

Answer (score 0):

Http response codes are only meant to handle http specific conditions so I don't think there is a correct answer as such. But some possibilities...

204 - "The server successfully processed the request and is not returning any content"

403 - "The request was valid, but the server is refusing action"

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status "423 Locked" might be suitable for a quarantined resource.